# How to use both minimum and maximum width?

Tags: html, css

The `root` div should have a minimum width, 100px is not fixed. I just put the `width: 200px` as a initial width. Because if I don't put a min-width it just expands to the full area. How can I make it more user friendly, It should just fit the width with the content not to break it until it takes 100% / full width.

```html
<div class="root">
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit, amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Blanditiis quam dignissimos perspiciatis ea illum ut.
</div>
```

```css
.root {
  width: 200px;
  max-width: 100%;
  padding: 1rem;
  background-color: #007bff;
  color: #fff;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try `display: inline-block`

```css
.root {
  display: inline-block;
  max-width: 100%;
  padding: 1rem;
  background-color: #007bff;
  color: #fff;
}
```

```html
 <div class="root">
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit, amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Blanditiis quam dignissimos perspiciatis ea illum ut.
</div>
```

Comment: @TheChosenUser better upvote an answer than to say thanks and you can accept it as well